Lazy Column/Row are not passing the touch events below | pointerInteropFilter is not working
After updating to the latest compose-bom 2024.09.00, Lazy Column/Row are not passing touch events to below composables.
Code Block:
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun LazyColumnDemo(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .clickable {
                    Log.d("LazyColumnDemo", "Box under LazyColumn clicked")
                },
        )
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .pointerInteropFilter {
                    return@pointerInteropFilter false
                }
        ) {
            items(listOf(1, 2, 3)) {
                Text(text = "Item $it")
            }
        }
    }
}


Sample Project: https://github.com/Naveed-Baloch/LazyViewsPlayground
Kindly Checkout before & after branches to see the difference.
Before 
After 
